# Does anybody know comprehensive fake data generator for MySQL that can be used right away from sql-script?

Tags: mysql

Yes, of course, I know, there are many different generators created on Javascipt, php, etc. and even applications and web-services that allow generating sql.

But I’d like to have sql functions library which can be used during generating data right away from MySQL script and stored procedures.

Now I'm creating my own helper functions (and it’s quite tedious) that work roughly like bellow:
(fl_* - are functions that return fake data of corresponding type and features.)

```
-- create a fake user:
call sp_user_add(fl_login(), fl_email(), fl_gender(), @user_id);

-- add a fake post:
call sp_post_add(@user_id, fl_title(true, 1, 10), fl_body(true, 3, 20), @post_id);
```

Comment: Bear in mind that recommendation questions [are discouraged here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (item 4) - historically we've found that they attract spam and discursive answers. You may get answers in the comments though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know [mysql random data generator stored procedure](https://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/generate-random-test-data-for-mysql-using-routines).

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.generatedata.com/. Here you can select the SQL-Tab and select the number of rows you want to get created. The result is a SQL-script you can copy-paste. I found this very handy...

Comment: Looks good, however I’d like to have an sql functions library to use from my sql-script.

Comment: I've added an example to the quesion.

Comment: just paste the generated SQL code from generatedata.com directly in your script

Comment: Of course, it’s easy to past SQL, when you are adding fake data into the table. But what if I have complicated logic of data filling and widely use stored procedures? In that case, it isn’t efficient to copy and past partials of generated sql. That why I’m looking for library of functions to generate data by my own.